# matplotlib - producing boxplots in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to plot several boxplots in one figure, on one axis. The data that I use for the boxplots, however, is too large to be read into memory at once. So I read it in chunks using pandas read_csv(). What I would like to do is to produce some boxplots in each iteration and add the new boxplots from iteration i to the same figure as the boxplots from iteration i-1, wihtout holding on to the data of iteration i-1.

I want to stress, that I do not need to update the data for an already existing boxplot. It's more like I get a new data column with each iteration and I want to display a boxplot of that column next to the existing boxplot.

E.g.: Say I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2))
```

Assume that I could read the columns only one after the other. How do I add the boxplot of the second column to the already existing boxplot of the first column to have the same result as ax.boxplot(df.values)?

Comment: You can call `plot(...)` (or whatever other plotting function you're using) multiple times in `matplotlib` and it will keep adding it to the same figure/subplot until you change it. You shouldn't need to do anything special. If you have a very large number of data points though, matplotlib may start to get unhappy / slow.

Comment: following your suggestion I tried `plt.figure() for i in xrange(2): plt.boxplot(df.ix[:,i].values)`. However, the boxplots get displayed ontop of each other. Taking Korem's answer into account I added the positions argument as `plt.boxplot(df.ix[:,i].values,positions=[i+1])`, but then the second boxplot replaces the first one.

Comment: @user3820991 I've added some sample code that works on my machine.

Comment: @Korem I try `plt.figure(); ax = plt.subplot(111); for i in xrange(2):
 ax.boxplot(df.ix[:,i].values,positions=[i+1])`. Again, the second boxplot replaces the first one. I found that in matplotlib 1.4 you can use `stats = cbook.boxplot_stats(data)` to get the median etc. for the boxplot and plot it by bxp(stats) (check out [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/bxp_demo.html#statistics-bxp-demo)). By this I could first produce the stats in a loop, which should require considerably less memory, and then plot them altoghter. I will post if that helped, but right now I cannot update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [boxplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot) method has a `positions` argument. Using that, you can guarantee, in a loop, that each boxplot (or multiple ones) is set in it's position.

Here's some code:

```
In [17]: x = pds.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))
In [18]: fig = plt.figure()
In [19]: ax = plt.subplot(111)
In [20]: for i in range(10):
    ...:     ax.boxplot(x.ix[:,i].values, positions = [i])
    ...:     
In [21]: ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 9.5)
In [22]: plt.show()
```

Comment: ok, the secret ingriedent was the `ax.set_xlim()`. Without it, the other positions were not replaced by succeeding ones (as I wrote above), but simply not displayed in the figure. Thanks!

Comment: @user3820991 Yea, I figured it was.

Answer (score 3):

Please note the following update, this:

```
ax.boxplot(x.ix[:,i].values, positions = [i])
```

Should be replaced by:

```
ax.boxplot(x.iloc[:,i].values, positions = [i])
```

as ix is deprecated.